# Change vertical scrollbar style

Tags: html, css, overflow

Is it possible to change the style of a vertical scrollbar? I would like to remove both arrows up and down.

```
<div class="msg-container-base">
  <message
    *ngFor="let message of thread.messages | async"
    [message]="message">
  </message>
</div>


.msg-container-base {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background: white;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scrollbar/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not recommended to play with the style of scrollbars because it has very bad portability (IE and Firefox won't support it), but if you still want to go that way, [here is a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qdw17vL2/2/) on how to play with the webkit style for the scrollbar

```
   /* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 20px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey; 
    border-radius: 2px;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: grey; 
    border-radius: 2px;
}

/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: darkgrey; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it but it only works on webkit browsers for now.
Alternatively, you could do the job with JQuery plugins.

Here's a way to do style your scrollbar with CSS:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
      background-color: #b46868;
} 

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); 
} 

::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
      background-color: #7c2929;
} 

::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
      background-color: black;
}
```